# LinkedMDB returns very few movies per country

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, linkedmdb

I am trying to get a list of movies per country (mainly China, Japan, Korea). I wanted to try out the LinkedMDB so i ran the following simple SPARQL

```
select distinct ?countryName where  {
  ?film a movie:film ;  movie:country ?country  .
  ?country rdfs:label ?countryName .
 }
```

The results could be found here [results](http://www.linkedmdb.org/snorql/?query=select%20distinct%20%3FcountryName%20where%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Ffilm%20a%20movie%3Afilm%20%3B%20%20movie%3Acountry%20%3Fcountry%20%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FcountryName%20.%0D%0A%20%7D%20&prefixes=PREFIX%20owl%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20xsd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20foaf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20oddlinker%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdata.linkedmdb.org%2Fresource%2Foddlinker%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20map%3A%20%3Cfile%3A%2FC%3A%2Fd2r-server-0.4%2Fmapping.n3%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20db%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdata.linkedmdb.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbpedia%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20skos%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2004%2F02%2Fskos%2Fcore%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dc%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20movie%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdata.linkedmdb.org%2Fresource%2Fmovie%2F%3E%0D%0A)
It is

```
"Saudi Arabia (Country)"
"Mozambique (Country)"
"Madagascar (Country)"
"Afghanistan (Country)"
"Pakistan (Country)"
"Sri Lanka (Country)"
"Bhutan (Country)"
"India (Country)"
```

1- Am I missing something or the dataset coverage per country is poor?
2- What other SPARQL end point sources I could add (besides dbpedia)?
P.S. DBPedia covergae was fairly poor as well (Only 76 movies,  [Chinese Films in Mandarin](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=select%20count%20%28distinct%20%3Ffilm%20as%20%3Fctf%29%20where%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%3Ffilm%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3AFilm%20%3B%20dbpedia-owl%3Acountry%20%3Fcty%20.%0D%0A%20%3Ffilm%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20.%0D%0A%20Filter%28regex%28%3Fcty%2C%22China%22%29%20and%20lang%28%3Flabel%29%3D%22zh%22%29%0D%0A%7Dorder%20by%20%3Fctf))

Comment: I don't think that [DBpedia's coverage](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=select+%3Fcountry+%28count%28distinct+%3Ffilm%29+as+%3FnFilms%29+where+%7B%0D%0A++%3Ffilm+a+dbpedia-owl%3AFilm+.%0D%0A++optional+%7B+%3Ffilm+dbpedia-owl%3Acountry+%3Fcountry+%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Agroup+by+%3Fcountry+%0D%0Aorder+by+desc%28%3FnFilms%29) is all that bad.  It is true that most movies don't have country information, though.

Comment: A filter like `regex(?cty,"China") and lang(?label)="zh"` shouldn't get you all that many results.  If you're seeing the string "China", then it sounds much more like the language of the label is English, not Mandarin.

Comment: Thanks Joshua, but is there anything wrong with my query from LinkedMDB? Hard to believe there is just 8 countries.

Comment: The movie( http://data.linkedmdb.org/page/film/10700) is a chinese movie and It has a country field , how come the LinkedMDB query reports no movie from China?

Comment: Look at what the values for its country property are, though: `<http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/country/CN>` and 
`<http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/country/HK>`.  By doing `?country rdfs:label ?countryName`, you're limiting yourself to countries that have an rdfs:label.  If `<http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/country/HK>`, doesn't have a label, you won't include it in your results.

Comment: Now, what is strange is that select distinct ?country { [] movie:country ?country } only returns 8 results.  However, linkedMDB has some strange execution limits (2500 results per query, I think).  It might be it pulls up the first 2500 results and just takes the countries from those.

Comment: Yes, I think it's something about the query limits.  You may notice that each of those countries has `rdf:type movie:country`.  If you search for countries that way, i.e., with `select distinct ?country { ?country a movie:country }`, then you get lots of results.

Comment: Great point Joshua. It worked. I reversed the order, in summary something  select * {?country a movie:country . ?film movie:country ?country }  and then it worked. Since you figured it out,  do you want to answer the result or  should I do this?

Comment: Also you mentioned something about the draw back of using filters like regex(?countryName,"China") so what would be the best way to filter the  countries for just China if I don't use this filter?